# What does the bar means for an integer (for example $\overline{323}^6$ and $\overline{35}^6$)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, decimal-expansion

It's in arithmetic context (not complex), and it's an integer (no decimal point).
The question was to find the answer of the product of 2 numbers $\overline{323}^6$ and $\overline{35}^6$, both in base 6, each of them has a bar on top, with a superscript 6 right next to the bar indicating the base.

I'm ok with 6, but what is the bar?

Comment: I suspect that the combination of the bar and the $6$ is intended to indicate that the number is to be read base six. In other words, your $\overline{323}^6$ is probably what I’d normally express as $323_{\text{six}}$ and others as $(323)_6$.

Comment: That looks like the bar is for clarity; so that the six would not be mistaken for an exponent $323^6$.

Comment: @Brian That's the exact notation I intended to describe

Comment: @YoussefDir: And I agree with Graham about the likely purpose of the bar. (Its technical name, by the way, is *vinculum* — not that many people use the name nowadays!)

Comment: I've seen the word *solidus* in British style text and it is used as parentheses.  Sometimes it is used as a "string" of number $\overline{ABC}=100A+10B+C$ distinguishing from $A\times B\times C$.

Comment: This is the kind of notation that's normally would be explained in the book. The comments here are plausible, but the notation is not standard, so the book should really tell what they mean by that notation. Which book do you use? At first glance my thought goes to the notation used in periodic decimal expansion, but with no fraction you would need a finite string - so another (maybe less likely) guess is that it would mean repeat six times.

Comment: @skyking actually it's related to an university course, and most probably it's just a way to state the base of a number.

Comment: @YoussefDir That may be the most probable way, but my point was that it's not a standard notation - therefore the book/professor/whatever should have defined what it/he/she meant by the notation.

Comment: @skyking You're probably right